# Matrix manipulation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an array of size (3x2). I want to insert these array vales into 4x3 zero arrays. How can I implement it in python?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((4,3))
b = np.ones((3, 2))
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(3):
        a[i,j] = b[i, j]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(x) < len(y):
    z = x.copy()
    z[:len(x)] += x
else:
    z = x.copy()
    z[:len(y)] += y
```